# No sum at 2 decimal

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I just start it to make a program in vb.net in combination with SQL.

I have 5 textboxes with 5 values with 2 decimals, which are `10,50`, `7,50`, `8,50`, `5,75`, and `8,25`. When I make a sum of this and put this in an other text box then it shows me the value `38,00` instead of `40,50`.

My code is as follows:

```
Public Sub plussen()

    Dim i1 As Integer
    Dim i2 As Integer
    Dim i3 As Integer
    Dim i4 As Integer
    Dim i5 As Integer
    Dim i6 As Integer

    For i1 = 5 To 20
        i2 = i1 + 396
        i3 = i1 + 496
        i4 = i1 + 596
        i5 = i1 + 696
        i6 = i1 + 896

        Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" + CStr(i1), True)(0).Text = (Val(Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" + CStr(i2), True)(0).Text) + Val(Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" + CStr(i3), True)(0).Text) + Val(Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" + CStr(i4), True)(0).Text) + Val(Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" + CStr(i5), True)(0).Text) + Val(Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" + CStr(i6), True)(0).Text)).ToString("F2")

    Next
End Sub
```

I have put this in a loop because I have 20 x 5 boxes to calculate. This is working but as I said with this code it does not sums up the decimals.

Does someone have an idea about my issue?

Comment: It would be best to sum the values before you convert them into text in the textboxes.

Comment: `Val` must not be able to work with a comma. Use a period `.` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is super lame but from the documentation:

> The Val function recognizes only the period (.) as a valid decimal
>   separator. When other decimal separators are used, as in international
>   applications, use CDbl or CInt instead to convert a string to a
>   number. To convert the string representation of a number in a
>   particular culture to a numeric value, use the numeric type's
>   Parse(String, IFormatProvider) method. For example, use Double.Parse
>   when converting a string to a Double.

So basically you need to use '.' instead of ',' in your textboxes or better yet switch from Val() to Double.Parse().

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9da280t0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hello Robert,  I have tested by using this double parse() instead of val () but the system  gives me an error , do I need to construct my code a bit more?

Comment: I made a parser that sort of acts like a hybrid between the Val function and the Double.TryParse method here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?850109-Convert-String-to-Double not only does it return a Boolean value if the conversion was successful, but it also uses the current culture to validate unary operators and mantissa(aka separator).

Answer (score 1):

Change your val() to Convert.ToDecimal() and use CultureInfo("fr-FR") to specify the decimal format.

e.g.

```
Convert.ToDecimal("10,5", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"))
```